# How to change search key on a RESTful API's URL?

Tags: json, postgresql, api, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use github's API, and find users by ID and not by username.

The URL to access to an  infos is *https://api.github.com/users/$USERNAME*

How can i find them by ID and not by name ?

I found [this](http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/more-complex-rest-requests.html) but it didn't worked for me with https://api.github.com/users?id=XXXXX

**EDIT:** The following answers works perfectly for the github api, but with the other one i'm working with, it don't, it only have a search by id, but i need one with a name.

Example to find a Team i have to use *http://footbar.fr/api/zinedine/club/2554/* , 2554 represent the ID of the team on the Database. I need to find them by name, but any of the solution that are proposed on Google works for me.

**EDIT 2:** The answer given below is perfect. I can't do requests to this "footbar" api because they didn't allowed it. Thanks, Solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been dealing with this apis for some time and it's really easy, but it's not official as they don't say it anywhere at their API

It seems that in github there's an undocumented way to do that, and that's simple:
    https://api.github.com/user/:id

As an example, you can see it in action: [Example of getting user by ID](https://api.github.com/user/1)